# How to get role name in jenkins from the logged in user id thorugh groovy workflow

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, role-based-access-control

My requirement is to get the role name from the role based strategy respective to the user logged in jenkins through groovy script console...currently i am not getting any predefined method for this.